# Anomaly detection for Google Analytics in realtime

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to detect anomalies in google analytics events like page views or custom events. 
I tested the [custom alert](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033021) feature from google itself. The period for those alerts are per day, week or month. What I'm looking for is a realtime detection. It would be useful to define rules for alerts like a maximum divergence between two points in time. For example [now, now - 15 minutes] or [now, now - 24 hours] or [now, now - 7 days]. Some solutions provide alerts when fixed threshold got passed (like [observe.io](https://opserv.io)). But thats not very helpful for highly fluctuating numbers that depend on weekday and daytime (like page views).

I would be thankful for any tips how to detect anomalies in GA in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

I agree thereshold solutions is not a good idea for detect anomalies in time series. Because they generally are set by the user, rather than learned, which can be a time consuming and difficult process when monitoring many data streams.

Moreover, they need to be adjusted as the environment changes, so manual real-time maintenance is needed.

Besides, since they don’t take temporal sequences into account, simple thresholds cannot identify pattern changes that take place within the range. I recommend you use methods for anomaly detection in time series or change point detection.

You can googling about this topics and you'll find several algorithms. For realtime analisys, i also can recommend softwares like MOA (http://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) and Numenta (https://numenta.com/).